# Property or method "$v" is not defined using Vuelidate

Tags: vue.js

**Error:**

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "$v" is not defined on the instance but
> referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive,
> either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
> initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at resources\assets\js\components\products\Product_create.vue

I'm using Vue.js and Vuelidate as validator,
I've copied and pasted this code from here https://jsfiddle.net/Frizi/b5v4faqf/ but it still doesn't work :

**Vue Component :**

```html
    <template >
      <input v-model="$v.text.$model" :class="status($v.text)">
      <!-- <pre>{{ $v }}</pre> -->
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import { required, minLength, between } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'
      export default {
         data() {
           return {
        text: ''
            }
           },
           validations: {
            text: {
            required,
            minLength: minLength(5)
          }
        },
        methods: {
            status(validation) {
            return {
                error: validation.$error,
              dirty: validation.$dirty
            }
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

**App.js**

```js
    require('./bootstrap');
    
    window.Vue = require('vue');
    window.VueRouter = require('vue-router').default;
    window.VueAxios = require('vue-axios').default;
    window.Axios = require('axios').default;
    window.VueFormWizard = require('vue-form-wizard');
    window.Vuelidate = require('vuelidate').default;
    import 'vue-form-wizard/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.css';

    Vue.use(VueRouter,VueAxios,axios,VueFormWizard,Vuelidate);

    const ProductOptionCreate = Vue.component('po-create',require('./components/products/ProductOption_create.vue'));
    const ProgressModal = Vue.component('vue-modal',require('./components/ProgressModal.vue'));
    const ProductIndex = Vue.component('product-list',require('./components/products/Product_index.vue'));
    const productshow = Vue.component('productshow',require('./components/products/ProductOption_show.vue'));
    const ProductCreate = Vue.component('product-create',require('./components/products/Product_create.vue'));
    

    const app = new Vue({
      el:'#app',
    
    });
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: You are not defining $v, you should define it under App.js

Comment: @RodrigoMata can u tell me how it's work?

Comment: As far as I can tell, [`Vue.use()`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-use) takes only **one** argument. You are attempting to pass it **five**.

Comment: Sorry, `Vue.use()` takes **one** or **two** arguments, the first being the required plugin and the second being an optional configuration object

Comment: ohh oke thanks a lot broo, how about if i have five? what should i do? @Phil

Comment: Separate calls to `Vue.use()` for each of them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that $v is not defined at a component level, and it is because of the order of your components, you need to reorder them like so:

```
// ... other stuff
import 'vue-form-wizard/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.css';

Vue.use(Vuelidate);

const ProductOptionCreate = // ... rest of your components
```

Comment: Was looking at this [thread](https://github.com/monterail/vuelidate/issues/99) and it appears to be something related to the order

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem was that the validation was declared within the data property of the component and not as a direct property of the component.

So

```
export default {
     validations: {
        text: {
        required,
        minLength: minLength(5)
      },
     data() {
       return {
           text: ''
        }
       },
       
    },
    ........
```

instead of

```
export default {
     data() {
       return {
          text: ''
        }
       },
       validations: {
        text: {
        required,
        minLength: minLength(5)
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason `$v` is not available on your instance is because you haven't instantiated the Vuelidate plugin. And that's because you tried to streamline the call to `Vue.use()`.
Your current `Vue.use()` call only instantiates the first plugin (`VueRouter`) and passes `VueAxios` plugin object as `VueRouter`'s config object. All subsequent arguments are ignored.

To streamline your calls to `Vue.use()`, you can't simply add more arguments to it.

Instead of this erroneous syntax (which breaks instantiation of all but first plugin):

```
Vue.use(VueRouter, VueAxios, axios, VueFormWizard, Vuelidate);
```

... you could use:

```
[[VueRouter], [VueAxios, axios], [VueFormWizard], [Vuelidate]]
  .forEach(args => Vue.use(...args));
```

With Typescript: unfortunately, TS parser wrongly includes `0` arguments as a possible outcome of the spread operator in the above case, so you'd need to suppress it using:

```
[
  [VueRouter],
  [VueAxios, axios],
  [VueFormWizard],
  [Vuelidate]
  /* @ts-ignore: TS2557, TS wrong about array above having empty members */
].forEach(args => Vue.use(...args));
```

... at least for now (`"typescript": "^3.9.7"`).

The above syntax is the exact equivalent of:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
Vue.use(VueFormWizard);
Vue.use(Vuelidate); // <= this is what you were missing, basically
                    // but your syntax also broke VueAxios and VueFormWizard install
```

On a personal note: although a tad more repetitive, I actually find the `Vue.use()` syntax cleaner in this case (more readable).

Answer (score 1):

The validations should be defined in a component in order to initialize this.$v

I had a typo and didn't realized I was declaring validations inside methods.

```
methods: {

   validations: {
      isUScitizen: { required },
   },
}
```

And I was trying to access this.$v which was undefined because the component didn't had validations defined.

Answer (score -9):

You must specify this.$v and there will be no error

Comment: Saying just this does not give any reasons why it wound't give an error. Explaining more would be helpful